# Django Name Error

Tags: django, django-urls

I have the following code in my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^testModule/',include(testModule.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and testModule is my app name which includes :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
]
```

And my views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
# Create your views here.
```

However, i get the following error while running the server:

> line 20:  url(r'^testModule/',include(testModule.urls)), 
>   NameError: name 'testModule' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't imported `testModule` in your main urls.

Comment: "from django.contrib import testModule." I imported it. Now I get an error as : cannot import name testModule

Comment: Yes. Why would you think it's in 'django.contrib'? It's presumably in your app.

Comment: i.e just use "import testModule" or "import testModule.urls"

Comment: Now I am getting another error as "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urls'"

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but solved it like this:

- add "import testModule" to your urls.py
- add "from django.conf.urls import url" to your urls.py **in the app directory, in this case testModule**

---

Once done you will get a "Page not found at/" error when you reload 127.0.0.1:8000. This is bacause the url to your app is actually at 127.0.0.1:8000/testModule